# Caddy forward-proxy configuration and usage request syntax

Tags: http, https, proxy, caddy

I have an old app that was working fine using cURL to make a request to a server, but now cannot connect due to upgraded requirements for TLS2.1 or newer on the server end. I'm trying to use Caddy as a forward-proxy to upgrade the connection from http to the latest https standards. The downloaded Cadde.exe was configured with the ForwardProxy plugin built-in. This is my configuration so far:

Caddy file:

```
http://localhost:4646
forwardproxy
```

Caddy.exe launches successfully.

Tried variations of requests from the app like these:

```
http://localhost:4646/https://www.google.com
https://localhost:4646/https://www.google.com
http://localhost:4646/http://www.google.com
http://localhost:4646/www.google.com
```

I'm not sure if any of these requests are the correct syntax for forward-proxy requests?

The response received is: 503 Service Unavailable :(

```
Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
Adding handle: conn: 0x2d780f0 
Adding handle: send: 0
Adding handle: recv: 0
Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1

- Conn 0 (0x2d780f0) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0

  Trying 127.0.0.1...

Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 4646 (#0)

GET /http://www.google.com HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: libcurl-agent/1.0
Host: localhost:4646
Accept: */*


HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable

HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable

Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

Retry-After: 3

Retry-After: 3

Server Caddy is not blacklisted

Server: Caddy

Server: Caddy

X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

Date: Tue, 03 Jul 2018 22:45:51 GMT

Date: Tue, 03 Jul 2018 22:45:51 GMT

Content-Length: 24

Content-Length: 24
```

Any help would be much appreciated!